# how to save text from richtext box to text document in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm taking value from richtextbox and i want to save it in new text document
[image: Value how I want to save in text document]

[image: How it stores it]

I Want to save text of rich text box in text document as i write in rich text box but it stores like shown in image

My Code

```
Using Sw As StreamWriter = File.CreateText(path)
            Dim number As String = RichTextBox1.Text
            Sw.WriteLine(number)

        End Using
```

Please help

Comment: What did you try to solve the problem?

Comment: I want to save rich text box value in text document as it is i write in rich text box but it saves like i show in image

Comment: I think, there may be a problem using the right codepage. Try either `Using Sw As New StreamWriter(path)` or `Using Sw As New Streamwriter(path, False, <YourEncoding>)`.

Comment: `File.WriteAllLines(path, RichTextBox1.Lines)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that both the `TextBox` and the `RichTextBox` control uses **LF** (*Line Feed*) as their newline format, but Windows's newline format is actually **CR + LF** (*Carriage Return* + Line Feed), which is what Notepad expects it to be.

The line breaks are there, Notepad just doesn't render them.

To fix this you can either replace all LFs with `Environment.NewLine` (which adapts to the current system) before saving:

```
Dim number As String = RichTextBox1.Text.Replace(vbLf, Environment.NewLine)
Sw.Write(Number)
```

...or you can save it line-by-line instead using the `StreamWriter.WriteLine()` method (which uses CR + LF for line breaks):

```
Using Sw As StreamWriter = File.CreateText(path)
    For Each Line As String In RichTextBox1.Lines
        Sw.WriteLine(Line)
    Next
End Using
```

**Read more:**

- [**Newline - Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) (Line Feeds)
- [**Carriage return - Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return)

Comment: Thank you Thank you So much :)

Answer (score 0):

After each Write, perform .Write(Environment.NewLine)